# What does "Waiting for DAS to start" mean in GlassFish 3?

Tags: installation, glassfish, application-server

I try to install the Glassfish 3 on my PC. I used the installation exe from https://glassfish.java.net/de/downloads/3.0.1-final.html

I started the Installer which installed Glassfish. I created a domain and then I opened asdadmin.bat and typed `start-domain mydomain`.

There I get:

```
Waiting for DAS to start..................fail to start domain:mydomain did not start in 60 seconds.......
```

What does `"DAS"` mean? I have no knowledge and couldn't find anything helpful via Google.

Answer (score 3):

DAS stands for "Domain Administration Server" in glassfish. The [administration guide](https://glassfish.java.net/docs/4.0/administration-guide.pdf) might also be helpful.